# How to solve for X in that equation? $(x + 2) ^ {(2x + 3)} = 2$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I tried to use log but it actually didn't work out.

$$(x + 2)^{(2x + 3)} = 2$$

Comment: Can you please show your effort which will make it easier for users to tailor their answers accordingly?

Comment: There is a rational solution which you can find by trial and error (if nothing else).  The other solution seems to require numerical methods.

Comment: These problems don’t have a good general solution. Sometimes, you can find solutions with trial and error, somethings, you can solve them with the Lambert $W$ function, which is very specifically designed for (some) questions like this. I’m not seeing a way to use Lambert here, however.

Answer (score 1):

Applying logarithm base $2$, you can transform it to:
\begin{align*}
(2x+3)\log_2(x+2)=1.
\end{align*}
Then if $y = \log_2(x+2)$ then $2^y=x+2$, so:
\begin{align*}
(22^y-1)y&=1\\
2^{y+1}y-y-1&=0.
\end{align*}
You apply any numerical method to the above equation and you will have two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be a closed form solution, but this still works like on this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hvrsjypajb) where you can choose any real x in the domain of the left hand side function or leave it as the solution converges to (x=solution, y=solution) because of the properties of the identity function x:

$$(x+2)^{2x+3}=2\implies A_0=x=\frac{\ln(2)}{2\ln\left(x+2\right)}-\frac32=A_1\quad= \frac{\ln(2)}{2\ln\left({\frac{\ln(2)}{2\ln\left({\frac{\ln(2)}{2\ln\left(…+2\right)}-\frac12}\right)}-\frac12}\right)}-\frac32 = A_3\implies \quad x=\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n(x_0) =A_\infty, A_{n+1}(x) = \frac{\ln(2)}{2\ln(A_n(x)+2)}-\frac32 \implies x=-\frac74=-1.75, .55626257…, x_0\in \Bbb R$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!